# Why are there two different versions of the mean and variance for negative binomial distributions

Tags: statistics

On a wiki proof site, I've seen these formulas used for the mean and variance:

$E[X] = \frac{rp}{1-p}$ and $Var[X] = \frac{rp}{(1-p)^2}$. Yet on the Penn State site, they have these two different formulas: $E[X] = \frac{r}{p}$ and $Var[X] = \frac{r(1-p)}{p^2}$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Two** issues are involved:

- Is the negative binomial the distribution of the waiting time until a specified number of "successes" or until a specified number of "failures"?
- Is it the number of trials needed to get the specified number of "successes" (or, as the case may be, of "failures") or is it the number of trials that **do not** result in that many successes, or failures, before that number of "successes" or "failures" happens?

So we have four possibilities:

- It's the number of trials needed to get $r$ successes.  Then we have
  $$
  \mathbb E(X) = \frac rp, \quad \operatorname{var}(X) = \frac{rp}{(1-p)^2}.
  $$
- It's the number of failures before the $r$th success.  Then we have
  $$
  \mathbb E(X) = r\frac{1-p}{p},\quad \operatorname{var}(X) = \frac{rp}{(1-p)^2}.
  $$
- It's the number of trials needed to get $r$ failures.  Then we have
  $$
  \mathbb E(X) = \frac r{1-p}, \quad \operatorname{var}(X) = \frac{r(1-p)}{p^2}.
  $$
- It's the number of successes before the $r$th failure.  Then we have
  $$
  \mathbb E(X) = \frac{rp}{1-p},\quad \operatorname{var}(X) = \frac{rp}{(1-p)^2}.
  $$

One advantage to viewing it as the number of successes before the $r$th failure or as the number of failures before the $r$th success is that then it is an infinitely divisible distribution, and it naturally extends to the case where $r$ is not an integer.  In that case it is supported on the set $\{0,2,3,4,\dots\}$.  In the other cases it is supported on the set $\{r,r+1,r+2,r+3,\dots\}$.

Comment: Very good description of the sad lack of consensus about what $X$ counts, even in the case of the geometric. Unfortunately, elementary probability books usually choose to count the number of trials.

Comment: @AndréNicolas : Thank you.

Comment: +1 for a very nice answer. I would like to suggest an improvement. It is worth pointing out explicitly that the random variables in the first two bulleted items are related as $X_2 = X_1-r$ so that $$\mathbb E(X_1) = \frac rp, \quad \operatorname{var}(X) = \frac{rp}{(1-p)^2}$$ which naturally leads to $$\mathbb E(X_2)= \mathbb E(X_1)-r = \frac rp -r = r\frac{1-p}{p},\quad \operatorname{var}(X_2) = \operatorname{var}(X_1) = \frac{rp}{(1-p)^2}$$ and similarly for the next two bulleted items.

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of semantics about the meaning of "success" (typically $p$ in the context of a binomial distribution) and "failure" (typically $q=1-p$). If the meaning is reversed in the context of the negative binomial, you'll get the same result, once you interchange $p$ with $1-p$.

So, you saw the same thing (assuming you really saw $E[X] = \frac{r}{p}-1$).

Comment: No, I didn't see $\frac{r}{p}$ - 1. Here is the Penn State site: https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/80

Comment: Actually, there are four conventions; see my answer.